# System.ExecutionEngineException thrown when starting debug with development server already running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-development-serv, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASPMVC project (vb.net; ASPMVC-2 if it makes any difference) in VS2010.  It's been fine for some years, but now I have a weird situation.  If I do the following:

1. Start debug mode in VS
2. Go through the site
3. Stop debugging but leave the asp.net development server running so that i can still test.
4. Put VS back into debug mode

Then the site runs fine for the first couple of steps but when it gets to a certain line of code it throws a System.ExecutionEngineException.  The development server then stops (I only see the execption becuase VS is in debug mode - the web browser just says "cannot connect" and the action filter which usually logs errors to a database doesn't run either because the whole web server process bails out).  If I, without changing anything, simply put VS back into debug mode then it works perfectly, without throwing any exception on the problematic command.  This happens almost every time (the exception that is, it's always OK if I do a clean start of the development server).

The row which causes the problem is an if statement using .ContainsValue() on an object which is of type SortedDictionary(Of Integer, String).

The full exception message is:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
  Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
  InnerException:
```

All I can find on MSDN is that this exception should never happen!  Googling throws up a couple of people meeting this exception, sometimes tied to a specific machine, but no real explanations.  I haven't had a problem before and have been developing this site on this machine for some years now.  The row which triggers the exception is new in this version so that may not say much.

Does anyone have any ideas?  The fact that it always works on a clean start is slightly comforting, but I'm not happy about shipping the code until I know why it does this and can prevent it.

Comment: I tried taking the .ContainsValue() to a boolean variable first and it is this that trigers the error, not the if statement.  If I instead of calling .ContainsValue loop over the dictionary and check manually then I do not get the exception.  Is there an inherant instability in SortedDictionary.ContainsValue() ?